# Comma separated value inside IN clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql

```
Create table #temp (name varchar(10) , email varchar(5000))
Insert into #temp values ('sam', 'sam@email.com,pam@email.com,kam@email.com')
Select * from #temp

Create table #temp2(id int, email2 varchar(5000))
Insert into #temp2 values (1, 'sam@email.com')
select * from #temp2
```

But when I try to select from below query then its not working.

```
Select * from #temp2 Where email2 in (Select email from #temp)
```

I want to pass email in the below format then it will work. 'sam@email.com','pam@email.com','kam@email.com'
IS there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you storing delete data at all is the real question here. Don't. Fix the design.

Comment: Please pick a duplicate from any of the results of searching for `[tsql] in clause comma delimited list`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
select t2.* 
from #temp2 t2
where exists (
    select 1 from #temp t where ',' + t.email + ',' like ',%' + t2.email + '%,'
)
```

Note, however, that this is a rather inefficient approach. Storing delimited lists is a typical anti-pattern in relational databases. I would recommend storing in each email in a separate *row* rather than in a delimited list. With this set-up at hand, the query that you attempted would work just fine.

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716) (this is a MySQL question but most observations do apply to any database).